# Rspec custom formatter that can print asserts that pass

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have multiple asserts for a single 'it' block. For example:

```
class Cat
  attr_reader :name, :age
  def initialize
    @age = 7
    @name = 'max'
  end

end

describe "Cat" do
    it "should have stuff" do
       cat = Cat.new
       cat.name.should == 'max'
       cat.age.should == 7
    end
end
```

I want a custom formatter that can not only print out the 'describe' statements and the 'it' statements but also every 'assert'. So the above would produce the following output on success:

Cat

- List item

  - should have stuff

    - cat name should == 'max'
    - cat age should == 7

Is it even possible to hook into the rspec assertions? From my research it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Can you share the documentation you share at your work for the rspec? Asking out of curiosity :)

Comment: I can put up a full rspec on Github if you want

Comment: Actually I am also learning rspec.. so I was checking if you have a better documentation than me or not? :D

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using a context and the 'its' assertions https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1063

Comment: Just so others don't get the wrong idea, I have to say "not really". :-)  The alternative that Myron described in the issue comment above involves significantly rephrasing your example. As you've written it, `cat.name` and `cat.age` have already been evaluated by Ruby before any RSpec code is involved, so it's effectively impossible to produce the output you're looking for based on the example you showed.